# tearing pin interrupt problem of the LCD driver

Tags: stm32, lcd

Using st7789 tearing pin interrupt for synchronization of lcd display. But getting interrupt at very high rate hence all other tasks are getting delayed. Help me in configuration of tearing pin interrupt at lower rate so other task will get MCU time and get executed.
Using stm32l4 with st7789 driver to drive TFT LCD display.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You are probably writing right code but nobody could be sure, right? So for people to help you please include relevant code for review.

Comment: do you really need it?